# How can I center a table with width more than 100%?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

I would like to center a table with more than 100% width on a webpage.
On my wordpress webpage I have a plugin which is creating a calender table for me automatically. Unfortunately my theme is limiting the space on my webpage to only a portion of my screen. The rest on the right and left is white space.

I am fine with this behavior on the other sides, but the calender table would be more beautiful if the calender table would dynamically adapt to the screen resolution and increase to the whole screen to the right and to the left. Therefore I think I have to increase the width of the table to more than 100%, because 100% is just as it is now.
Here is the link to my webpage: https://www.greendroid.de/kalender

If I use the following code snippet, the calender gets bigger, but is not centered anymore. The right table columns are not longer visible

```
.ics-calendar-month-grid
{
    width:150%;
}
```

I tried different methods to center the table afterwards again, but no CSS snippet worked for me.
Anyone has an idea how I can adapt the width of the table automatically to the screen size on my webpage?
Thanks and best regards
NKL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it will grow from the current position you only have to apply negative margin to the half of the amount over 100... so (150-100)/2=25 so appliying -25% margin to the left side will do:

```
.ics-calendar-month-grid {
    width: 150%;
    margin-left: -25%;
}
```

It will work.

**Update**

To make it responsive just add/update your CSS with:

```
.ics-calendar-month-grid {
    width: 150%;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1699px) {
    .ics-calendar-month-grid {
        width: 125%!important; margin-left: -12.5%!important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1415px) { 
    .ics-calendar-month-grid {
         width: 110%!important; margin-left: -5%!important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1415px) {
    .ics-calendar-month-grid {
         width: 100%!important; margin-left: 0!important;
    }
}
```

This is an approach that should work... you can add all the steps you need/want just take a look in chrome tools (hit F12) the resolution you have on the top right corner to add a specific step. Note that i've put `!important` declaration because i played with you website directly with chrome developer tools.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. But unfortunately on smaller screens the table is now on the left and right side outside of the screen. I would like to get this dynamically adapted to the available screen width. Do you have an idea for that?

Comment: You have applied a width 1.5 points of the container width... if the container is the screen margin it won't fit... You can do it using JavaScript to have full control or using responsive CSS and controlling the layout width. Let me know if you need some working code...

Comment: I think the best way would then be responsive CSS because I can easily add CSS via the Design->Customizer view in wordpress.
I know I have some responsive CSS on my site to change a <div> from horizontal to vertical view on mobile devices, but there I was using a fixed Pixel-Width for changing the layout.
Can you support with an resp-CSS example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow! Your update code example is working like a charm. Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It's a Wordpress theme that allows the use of full-width elements. So, either you add the class `.alignfull` to that element/section in the HTML code or (if the block editor lets you) you choose "full width" from the alignment selection menu of that block in the editor .

Comment: I don't get where to put this .alignfull. Can you help me further at which point in wordpress I would have to enter this?
The calendar is inserted by the use of an shortcode. In theory I have access to the plugins html code, but I try not to change plugin code because of plugin-updates which would require the changes again and again.

Comment: It depends on the shortcode and the plugin. If the plugin accepts classes in the shortcode, you could add it there. Just try it - add `class="alignfull"` before the closing bracket of the shortcode to see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately the `class="alignfull"` at the end of the shortcode before the closing bracket does not make any change. Perhaps I also need a CSS definition for it? Or is `alignfull` a standard Wordpress class?

Comment: Which Wordpress editor do you use to insert the shortcode -  the old one (pre WP5) / "classic editor" or the new block editor? If its the block block editor, open the advanced settings in the right column. The last input field (additional CSS classes) allows you to define a class (in this case "alignfull"). Or are you inserting the shortcode in the php template?

Comment: I am using the Classic Editor for the complete webpage, but I tried to change it temporarily. There is no "Advanced Settings" in the right column. I only have the german translation from the block editor. Can you tell me some content below this "Advanced Settings" tab? Perhaps it is somehow translated different in the german version. I couldn't find anything related to "Add classes" in the available tabs.

Comment: While the block is selected in the editor, make the "settings" column  visible ("Einstellungen" / Klick auf Zahnradsymbol rechts oben). In there at the bottom "Erweitert > Zusätzliche CSS-KLasse/n"

Comment: Ah thanks. Now I have found it. Unfortunately the Block Editor is not allowing to add this class to a "Shortcode-Block". I can use a separate paragraph with text: Then the "Advanced" tab and the "Additional classes" field is visible. For shortcode the editor is not showing this field...

Comment: One more thing to try: You could try to use a group block (Block "Gruppe"), set that to full width (using the align symbol menu at the left top of the block) and insert a shortcode block *inside*  that.

Comment: Then I can indeed assign the additional class to the group block. Unfortunately it is not changing the behavior of the side. Perhaps it gets overwritten by the shortcode afterwards...